# Can I use the python library 'xmlschema' to create XML-Documents from scratch?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

There are some schema definition files (xsd). They can be read with the library [xmlschema](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I can use it to validate or convert some existing XML-Documents. That is fine.

But I have to create entire new XML-Documents from scratch. How can the library help to reach the goal?

Addition:

I like to provide some more information. The XSD-Files are provided by a third party and I cannot make them public. But I can red them without a problem with:

```
import xmlschema    
schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema('schema.xsd')
print(schema)
```

> XMLSchema10(name='schema.xsd', namespace='some:namespace')

Further the documentation says, that the root element for the xml-document has the namespace ´some:namespace´.

Comment: Where does your data come from, and what form is it in? The phrase "from scratch" suggests the data is only in your head, but I suspect that's not the case...

Comment: The xsd-files are provided by a third party. They can be read with no problem into a XMLSchema10 Object.

Comment: If you have Eclipse, it’s only few clicks to create a template xml, find a description [here](https://sbnwiki.astro.umd.edu/wiki/Eclipse:_Creating_a_New_XML_File_from_an_XSD_Schema_File)

Comment: Can be done with java XmlBeans if that helps: `XMLBEANS_LIB='/home/lmc/Downloads/xmlbeans-5.1.0/lib' /home/lmc/Downloads/xmlbeans-5.1.0/bin/xsd2inst -name gpx gpx.xsd > gpx.xml`

Comment: @testo I was asking about where the data comes from, not where the schema comes from.

Comment: @Michael, sorry. The data came from some example xml-files.

Comment: Then it looks like you want to do an XSLT transformation from one XML format to another. You don't need a schema to do that, though a schema-aware processor will help you with debugging once you've mastered how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

use [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/). as the name suggests, you can parse an XML string to dict and vice versa, "unparse" a dict to an XML document

Comment: correct. But I have to know how to build the dict from scratch, so it is basically the same problem. What I found out so far is, that I have namespaces of the root element and a list of xpath definitions.

Comment: What shape is your original data?